# Email not valid / no account for

Tags: support, accounts

I am having a hard time to understand why I can only login to Stack Exchange sites through Facebook login. And when I try to login with my email it says that there is no user with my email.

Because I want to access Stack Exchange sites from my work, where Facebook is not allowed I tried to login with my e-mail but I am stuck with this problem. The image below display the error message and there is also a print screen of my e-mail in my Stack Overflow account.

[image: No account with this email found]

Can I do something to fix this?

Comment: Did you just want the whole world to know your email address? You might want to edit the screen shot to hide the email address if you don't.

Comment: You probably cannot login via your mail because you've registered via Facebook OpenID. If so, StackOverflow has no record of your mail address. I don't know if it's possible to create a StackExchange login for the same account though...

Comment: Take a look at your logins - on your profile page you will find a "my logins" link. You can use **any** of those to log-in. You can also add additional openId providers there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites do not authenticate logins on their own.  They relay on external authentication methods, chiefly OpenID, but Facebook is also supported.  Stack Exchange does host its own OpenID provider, but that is technically separate from your login to any of the sites.  You don't need to have a Stack Exchange login in order to login.

So it appear you are trying to log into your Stack Overflow account using the Stack Exchange Open ID provider with your Facebook credentials.  Unless you have actually registered for a Stack Exchange Open Id with this email address, this is not going to work.

What you need to do is when you have access to Facebook, you need to create a secondary login for your account.  Then you can authenticate your login credentials at times Facebook is not available.  For the secondary login, you can use your gmail account as Google is an Open ID provider, or you can create a new Stack Exchange Open ID, or you can create a profile at any other Open ID provider you want.

You can find a set of instructions [Add new email to login credentials](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166067/add-new-email-to-login-credentials)